# Kiddush Levana as "Life Insurance?"

Tags: death, superstition, kiddush-levanah

The [Kaf HaChaim (426:12)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.426.2?lang=bi&p2=Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.426.12.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en)
writes

> – בס' אור חדש וגם שמעתי שמי שיקדש הלבנה מיום שיקדשה לא ידאג שימות
>   באותו החדש מאותו היום ואילך עכ"ל. והביאו א"ר וש"ץ שם. והיינו שלא ימות
>   מיתה משונה - I heard someone who says Kiddush Levana shouldn't worry that they'll die that month from that day onward. Meaning, dying from a strange death.

What is unique about Kiddush Levana that there is a special death protection?

Comment: Life insurance does not protect or prevent someone from dying. We will all die eventually no matter what. It just provides a death benefit for a beneficiary/beneficiaries who may suffer a financial loss from the death of the insured.

Comment: I read it that "Life Insurance" was meant figuritively, as in insuring life over death.

Comment: @gamli wouldn't that be life ensurance?